# How to put a border of equal size on both sides of a list inside a div

Tags: html, css

I'm actually trying to display a list of alerts in a `<div>` center in the middle of the page + responsive. The last problem I have is the border who is only on the left side of the list and not on the right side (look the images)

I would like to have the border to the both sides:
[image]

There is the code

```css
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.liAlerte {
    border-style: solid;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    word-break: break-all;
}


@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .alerteAllOnePagecenter {}

    .alerteAllOnePagecenter-inner {
        left: 25%;
        top: 25%;
        position: absolute;
        width: 50%;
        height: 300px;
        background: #c9d0db;
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 500px;
        max-height: 500px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .alerteAllOnePagecenter {
        left: 50%;
        top: 25%;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .alerteAllOnePagecenter-inner {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: -250px;
        height: 300px;
        background: #c9d0db;
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 500px;
        max-height: 500px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="alerteAllOnePagecenter">
  <div class="alerteAllOnePagecenter-inner">
  <ul clas="ulAlerteAllOnePage">
      <li class="liAlerte">
        <a><span>Level of the alert maybe</span>
              <span class="time">Since X minutes</span>
              <span class="message">description of the alert</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="liAlerte"><a><span>Level of the alert maybe</span>
              <span class="time">Since X minutes</span>
              <span class="message">description of the alert</span>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="liAlerte"><a><span>Level of the alert maybe</span>
              <span class="time">Since X minutes</span>
              <span class="message">description of the alert</span>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="liAlerte"><a><span>Level of the alert maybe</span>
              <span class="time">Since X minutes</span>
              <span class="message">description of the alert</span>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <div class="text-center">
              <a>
                  <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
              </a>
          </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because default margin applied by **ul,li** tags you can remove that using following styles

```
ul,li{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```css
ul,li{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
  
}

.liAlerte {
    border-style: solid;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    word-break: break-all;
}


@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .alerteAllOnePagecenter {}

    .alerteAllOnePagecenter-inner {
        left: 25%;
        top: 25%;
        position: absolute;
        width: 50%;
        height: 300px;
        background: #c9d0db;
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 500px;
        max-height: 500px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .alerteAllOnePagecenter {
        left: 50%;
        top: 25%;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .alerteAllOnePagecenter-inner {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: -250px;
        height: 300px;
        background: #c9d0db;
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 500px;
        max-height: 500px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="alerteAllOnePagecenter">
  <div class="alerteAllOnePagecenter-inner">
  <ul clas="ulAlerteAllOnePage">
      <li class="liAlerte">
        <a><span>Level of the alert maybe</span>
              <span class="time">Since X minutes</span>
              <span class="message">description of the alert</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="liAlerte"><a><span>Level of the alert maybe</span>
              <span class="time">Since X minutes</span>
              <span class="message">description of the alert</span>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="liAlerte"><a><span>Level of the alert maybe</span>
              <span class="time">Since X minutes</span>
              <span class="message">description of the alert</span>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="liAlerte"><a><span>Level of the alert maybe</span>
              <span class="time">Since X minutes</span>
              <span class="message">description of the alert</span>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <div class="text-center">
              <a>
                  <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
              </a>
          </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you need padding on both side you need to add **padding-left and padding-right** as follows

```css
ul{
  padding-left:50px;
  padding-right:50px;
  margin:0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
  
}

.liAlerte {
    border-style: solid;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    word-break: break-all;
}


@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .alerteAllOnePagecenter {}

    .alerteAllOnePagecenter-inner {
        left: 25%;
        top: 25%;
        position: absolute;
        width: 50%;
        height: 300px;
        background: #c9d0db;
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 500px;
        max-height: 500px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .alerteAllOnePagecenter {
        left: 50%;
        top: 25%;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .alerteAllOnePagecenter-inner {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: -250px;
        height: 300px;
        background: #c9d0db;
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 500px;
        max-height: 500px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="alerteAllOnePagecenter">
  <div class="alerteAllOnePagecenter-inner">
  <ul clas="ulAlerteAllOnePage">
      <li class="liAlerte">
        <a><span>Level of the alert maybe</span>
              <span class="time">Since X minutes</span>
              <span class="message">description of the alert</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="liAlerte"><a><span>Level of the alert maybe</span>
              <span class="time">Since X minutes</span>
              <span class="message">description of the alert</span>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="liAlerte"><a><span>Level of the alert maybe</span>
              <span class="time">Since X minutes</span>
              <span class="message">description of the alert</span>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="liAlerte"><a><span>Level of the alert maybe</span>
              <span class="time">Since X minutes</span>
              <span class="message">description of the alert</span>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <div class="text-center">
              <a>
                  <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
              </a>
          </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You removed the margin but I would like to have the same on the 2 sides is it possible ?¨

Comment: @jerom for that you need to add padding

Answer (score 0):

u can check either this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp) or u can use bootstrap where u can put ur content inside a div class="container" which makes it responsive and also will introduce padding to your content